# Algorthim to Allocate Resources

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sorting

I'm trying to allocate resources based on the given start and end date. I have to prevent overlapping and make sure the work can be completed between the start and end date. Knowing each person can work 8 hours.

For example
Start Date    End Date  Hours     User  Task
2011-11-01  -- 2011-11-23 -- 32 Adam Code

So if I add Adam for 2011-11-13 - 2011-11-20 10 Hours for Designing,  I have to make sure the work can be completed without overlapping and if not then suggest the best start and end date. I know this seems  a bit complicated, is there any algorithm I can use to get started?

Comment: Microsoft Project or any project management software will do it for you.

Comment: @SeanBarlow User is not asking for a software recommendation. It's not a very good question, but that's not a helpful comment, IMHO.

Comment: @AndrewBarber What should we tell him then? The algorithm he is looking for is called addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the difference between dates in hours and then compare with the time in hours column to decide.

Answer (score 1):

The [top-nodes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-nodes_algorithm) looks like it might be a good starting point.